# Fastest single core processor

Tags: cpu

I'm aware that processor clock speed can be misleading, and these days power scales with parallel execution and cores.

That said, how do I figure out which of today's standard x86-64 consumer/server processors would be the fastest for **single threaded** calculations?  (I use mainly C and JVM)

I've already got access to loads of cores of modest speed, but sometimes need fast single threaded operations, so wondering what would be the most suitable thing to buy

Comment: Depends on the type of calculations you're doing.

Comment: Sites like tomshardware have pretty good comparison charts to compare components so that might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What instruction set? x86/64? Power? Cell?

If you mean x86/64 then the chip with the highest clock speed is the Xeon X5677 (QC, 3.47Ghz) with the X5687 (QC, 3.6 Ghz) available shortly.

That said the way to get faster is via overclocking and Xeon's aren't often overclocked as they're focussed on stability, plus most overclockers find the i7's the best for that job. If you choose to go that way then the i7-980X is the fastest today (6C, 3.33Ghz) with the  i7-995X (QC, 3.6Ghz) also available shortly. The 980X has been overclocked to 5Ghz with liquid nitrogen.

Comment: Also, that Xeon should support Turbo Boost so should see at least +266 MHz during single-threaded load, passing the 3,8 GHz barrier without overlocking ^^

Comment: The question asked was which CPU was the fastest in single core execution, not which has the highest clock speed.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but perhaps this site can be useful:
http://www.spec.org/benchmarks.html#cpu
It has tons of results for all kind of cpu-s, only problem is searching through them.

Comment: Would vote this up, but my reputation is insufficient.